# django form template designer friendly

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am doing the django project right now. I love the principle of DRY. I have a form which can be applied to all other pages which needs it. I mean a generic form based from django docs. But in the form, there can be select type, file upload, checkbox, radio etc which I dont like the design of native html. I want to leverage the design of material with some customization. How can I do it? Below is my form and my form has checkbox, file upload and multiple select which I need to customize. In a nutshell, my question is how do I make my generic form designer friendly?

For now I am handling my form template as follow

```
<form class="form" role="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" for="{{ form.company.id_for_label}}">Company</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="{{ form.company.name }}" id="{{ form.company.id_for_label}}">
            <option value=""></option>
            {% for id, name in form.company.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{ id }}" class="option">{{ name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" for="{{ form.name.id_for_label}}">Job Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.name.name }}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label" for="{{ form.description.id_for_label}}">{{ form.description.label }}</label>
                <div class="markdownx">
                    {{ form.description|add_css:'form-control' }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" for="{{ form.category.id_for_label}}">{{ form.category.label }}</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="{{ form.category.name }}" id="{{ form.category.id_for_label}}">
            <option value=""></option>
            {% for id, name in form.category.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{ id }}">{{ name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" for="{{ form.city.id_for_label}}">{{ form.city.label }}</label>
        <input type="text" id="{{ form.city.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.city.name }}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label" for="{{ form.address.id_for_label}}">{{ form.address.label }}</label>
        <input type="text" id="{{ form.address.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.address.name }}" class="form-control">
    </div>
</form>
```

This way the code to show the form becomes so huge and its only 1 form. Its not good to write such huge code for the app with more than 8 10 forms.

The better way is

```
{% load add_css %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="text-center m-t-lg">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    {% if field.errors %}
                        <div class="form-group has-error">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                {{ field|add_css:'form-control' }}
                                <span class="help-block">
                                {% for error in  field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            {{ field|add_css:'form-control' }}
                            {% if field.help_text %}
                                <p class="help-block"><small>{{ field.help_text }}</small></p>
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But here is one difficulty I am facing. I can't check if its a file upload field or multiple select field etc so I can design them accordingly. Because sometime, I need to handle many divs to show it properly.

Is there any way to make the form template more flexible for the designer?

Comment: The ```{% else %}``` in the second template is bad indented.

Comment: it was the html beautify from sublime. I need to install better prettier plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arg `widget` in your field definition, and create some custom widget template. So you define them once, and you just have to care about printing field in your template. Here doc on [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/) et [custom widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/renderers/)

Comment: Do you mean to say something like this ? `widgets = {
            'established_year': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'})
        }`